# Solaris process memory usage increase but not forever

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, solaris, rogue-wave

On Solaris 10 I have a multithreaded process with a  strange behaviour. It manages complicated C++ structures (RWTVal or RWPtr). These structures are built from data stored in a database (using Pro*C). Each hour the process looks for new informacion in database, builds new structures on memory and it frees older data. But, each time it repeats this procedure, the process memory usage increases several MB (12/16MB).  Process's memory usage starts from 100M until near 1,4G.  Just to this point, it seems the process has memory leaks. But the strange behaviour is that after this point, the process stops to continue growing up anymore. When I try to look for memory leaks (using Purify tool) the process doesn't grow up and no significant leaks were showed. Did anyone found a similar behaviour or can explain what could be happening?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You should make that an answer. Sounds like the correct answer to me.

Answer (score 1):

It *probable* that the operating system doesn't actually "throw away" the old memory pages when you free the memory, because it will then be quicker for the application to allocate more memory if the OS don't have to allocate more pages. But only up to a limit of course.

Comment: Not just "probably". It's documented behaviour. The manpage for `free()` on Solaris says _"...  is executed, this space is made available for further allocation by the application, though not returned to the system."_ See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1465/free-3c.html

Comment: Yes, this is the problem: new malloc operations have to reuse the previous freed memory, but it seems that isn't happened. In a normal execution a process could grow a little bit when is processing because of this reusing memory. In my example, why wasn't it happening? After new tests I have discovered the stable point (1.4G) depends on the amount of memory I have to allocate in each operation. If I try to allocate bigger structures en the same operation the process arrives to the maximum 4G addressable capabilities (it's a 32-bit application) an dies. Thanks a lot.